# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is not running the ffmpeg command on centos

Tags: java, linux, ffmpeg

I am doing as below on centos machine

```
String fileName = "ffmpeg -i file:///home/xyz %d.png";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileName);
```

xyz is mp4 file and i want that to create number of different Image frames

when i am running by java application as above it is not working however if i try to do so directly on terminal it is working, please suggest as what might be wrong ?

Comment: how is %d set? that seems likely to be an invalid file. And do you get any sort of error message?

Comment: ffmpeg -i file:///home/xyz %d.png  is running fine when i run this on local terminal . Here  %d is creating different number for images ..

Comment: i tried removing %d also .. not working

Comment: 1) Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Apologies if this comes so late, hope it can be useful for somebody.
As @rodion was foreseeing, this is definitely related to ffmpeg specific output.

I had a run with `-nostats -loglevel 0` options, and then ffmpeg was correctly executed by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");`

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that the program is outputting a lot to standard out or error. If you do not consume this output, the Java program may hang. Use [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)`#getErrorStream()` and `getOutputStream()`, in a fashion like this:

```
is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
  System.out.println(line);
```

This will also help you analyze any error output from the command you run. You may need to do this for both streams.

Additionally, you may need to wait for the subprocess to terminate, using `Process#waitFor`, because otherwise your Java program might be finishing execution even though the spawned subprocess is still running in the background (unless this is what you want).